# How Open a new Window in Mainwindow with PyQT5 in Python?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, new-window

im totally new when it comes to programming. I want to create a Flashcard Application for Windows. So far i can tell my "programm" works fine, but i cant manage to open a new Window when i click on my widgets. I need to know how i can write the code corectly and specificly - where do i have to add what exactly.
Inside the new Window i would like to have a Textfield where i can write some notes, choose if i want to write the Text as "strong", "curved" and stuff like this.

I researched in the docs, tried something and it doesnt work like it should be.
I hope someone can help me to solve this "problem".I want to create a new Window when i click on "Decks" and the other buttons, that i have.
Else i would like to have a Menu in the top left Corner where i can click on "New Deck" or "Help" or something like this.

Here is my Code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1280, 900)
    self.setWindowTitle("Flashcards!")



def initUI(self):
    wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(wid)

    self.screenObject = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)


    self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
    self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.screenObject.width(), 2))
    self.line.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170)")

    self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
    self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 35, self.screenObject.width(), 2))
    self.line_2.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170)")


    self.topfont = QtGui.QFont()
    self.topfont.setBold(True)
    self.topfont.setWeight(75)
    self.topfont.setPointSize(9)
```

###########Buttons####################################################

```
    self.deckLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.deckLabel.setText("Decks")
    self.deckLabel.setFont(self.topfont)
    self.deckLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel::hover {color: rgb(100, 100, 100)}")
    self.deckLabel.mousePressEvent = self.clicked




    self.addLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.addLabel.setText("Add")
    self.addLabel.setFont(self.topfont)
    self.addLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel::hover {color: rgb(100, 100, 100)}")
    self.addLabel.mousePressEvent = self.clicked


    self.browseLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.browseLabel.setText("Browse")
    self.browseLabel.setFont(self.topfont)
    self.browseLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel::hover {color: rgb(100, 100, 100)}")
    self.browseLabel.mousePressEvent = self.clicked


    self.statsLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.statsLabel.setText("Stats")
    self.statsLabel.setFont(self.topfont)
    self.statsLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel::hover {color: rgb(100, 100, 100)}")
    self.statsLabel.mousePressEvent = self.clicked


    self.syncLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.syncLabel.setText("Sync")
    self.syncLabel.setFont(self.topfont)
    self.syncLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel::hover {color: rgb(100, 100, 100)}")
    self.syncLabel.mousePressEvent = self.clicked


    self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hbox.setSpacing(60)
    self.hbox.addStretch()
    self.hbox.addWidget(self.deckLabel)
    self.hbox.addWidget(self.addLabel)
    self.hbox.addWidget(self.browseLabel)
    self.hbox.addWidget(self.statsLabel)
    self.hbox.addWidget(self.syncLabel)
    self.hbox.addStretch()
    self.hbox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

    wid.setLayout(self.hbox)




def clicked(self, event):
    print("clicked!")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MyWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue. I wanted a popup window to be displayed when I clicked on a button. To do so, I simply created a function that is triggered when you click on the button. Very similar to your `clicked()` function.

In this function, you can define your new window parameters and display it.
Please note that you can use `.show()` if you want to generate this window and continue to process the code or `.exec_()` if you want to wait for the window to be closed before continuing the execution of your code.

In my case, it was displaying a popup window to warn the user that a restart is needed:

```
def restart(self):
    # Create a popup window
    self.w = QMessageBox()

    # Custom Texts
    self.w.setWindowTitle("GUI Version Check")
    self.w.setText("A newer version of the GUI is available.")

    # Custom Icons
    # use a file logo.svg to replace the default WindowIcon
    self.w.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.svg'))
    # Add a Warning Icon on the new window
    self.w.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)

    # Custom Button: rename Yes by Restart
    self.w.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes)
    b = self.w.button(QMessageBox.Yes)
    b.setText("Restart")

    # Start the window and wait for a user input
    self.w.exec_()

    # In my case restart the GUI here
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your Answer. I tried it out but its not what i was looking for. If i click onto my Widgets a second Window should open with a Textfield, where i can enter some Notes.

Comment: Well, this is how to generate a second window. You can configure it to be whatever you want. For example add a text field and a save button.